# Get text from selected link or button

Tags: c#, atata

I am navigating to say a Google page and sending the keystrokes like the Tab key for six times and I need to get the text of the highlighted link or button or any control which in this case would be the Privacy link

```
    [Test]
    public void GooglePageTabNavigation()
    {
        Go.To<GooglePage>().
            Wait(2).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            Wait(1).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            Wait(1).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            Wait(1).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            Wait(1).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            Wait(1).
            Press(Keys.Tab).
            .....
            //code to get text
            .....
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the following extension method:

```
public static class IPageObjectExtensions
{
    public static Control<TOwner> GetActiveControl<TOwner>(this IPageObject<TOwner> pageObject)
        where TOwner : PageObject<TOwner>
    {
        return pageObject.Controls.Create<Control<TOwner>>(
            "<Active>",
            new DynamicScopeLocator(so => AtataContext.Current.Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement()));
    }
}
```

And then use this method:

```
Go.To<GooglePage>().
    //...
    GetActiveControl().Content.Should.Equal("Privacy");
```

Comment: Excellent! @yevgeniy-shunevych thanks again for all the help, it worked like a charm ....